# How can I get number between specific words in string?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want to extract phone number from xml using regex.

```
....
 <address>phone number</address>
....

ex)<address>1234567890</address>
```

But sometimes that phone number gets prefixed with some unnecessary characters.

```
ex) <address>tel+1234567890</address>
```

I only need phone number.

I used `<address>.+?(\d+)</address>`

But this does not work properly.

How can I always get number regardless of the case when there is prefix word?

Comment: what have you tried code wise.. have you done a google search on RegEx and the tons of examples online for what you are looking for..?

Comment: Why RegEx? There are perfectly good XML parsers in .NET.

Comment: @nvoigt: in all fairness I think you would probably then still need a regex to remove extraneous characters beforehand.

Comment: @jay: What do you mean "But this does not work properly"? does it not matcfh anything? does it match the right thing sometimes and not others? Does it fail to compile? Does it do something else? Be precise in your error descriptions to help people help you.

Comment: Have you tried `<address>[^>\d]*(\d+)[^>]*</address>` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, your regex doesn't work because you don't make the `.+?` optional.
You can fix it like this `.*?` or  do something like below:

Regex:

```
 @"<address>[^>\d]*(\d+)[^>]*</address>"
```

Formatted:

```
 <address> [^>\d]* 
 ( \d+ )                       # (1)
 [^>]* </address>
```

Output:

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 51 , len 29 ) 
<address>1234567890</address>
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 60 , len 10 ) 
1234567890

---------------

 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 169 , len 33 ) 
<address>tel+1234567890</address>
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 182 , len 10 ) 
1234567890
```

Comment: Regex only needs to capture digits. @"(\d)+" will return desired match.

Comment: @dougvdotcom - just any `\d` ? Where does it start?

Comment: @sln: digits are always prefixed with text and not interrupted. Therefore just grouping by one or more digits is all he needs. Tested at http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx and performs as expected.

Comment: @dougvdotcom - `\d+` will also match the digits in this `<age>tel+1234567890</age>` but that doesn't look like something to match.

Answer (score 2):

You can use linq:

```
string number = "tel+12345678";
string filtered = new String(number.Where(x => Char.IsDigit(x)).ToArray());
```